# PostgreSQL to FileGDB doesn't keep joins

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to convert my geospatial PostgreSQL tables to a FileGDB (geodatabase) by using this command:

```
ogr2ogr --config FGDB_BULK_LOAD YES -f "FileGDB" C:\data.gdb -append -overwrite -mapFieldType Integer64=Real PG:"host=localhost user=postgres password=pass dbname=dbname tables=table1,table2"
```

The tables are joined by foreign key (reference). But after opening the created geodatabase in ArcGIS it doesn't seem like the tables are joined. Is there any way to tell the converter to join the specified tables?

Any other converters with join support?

Comment: Ogr2ogr works layer by layer and foreign keys, attribute indexes, views etc. are not transferred. It may be possible to create the foreign key constraints with ogrinfo and -sql option as post-process but I do not know how well FileGDB supports that.

Comment: @user30184 trying to make foreign key with ogrinfo -sql gives: `An invalid SQL statement was used.`

Comment: Use must include also a valid SQL statement `ogrinfo -sql "alter table xxx add ..." my_filegdb.gdb`

Comment: @user30184 yeah, I'm aware of that. that's what I did. `alter table` doesn't work.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you did and how did it fail so others can have a try. Unfortunately I do not know FileGDB. How do you usually create foreign keys into it?

Comment: @user30184 Sure. This was what I tried: `ogrinfo data.gdb -sql "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_col1 FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES table2 (col1)"`. Returned: ERROR 1: Failed at executing 'ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_col1 FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES table2 (col1)' (An invalid SQL statement was used.)

Comment: File geodatabase is **not** a full SQL implementation. It does not support constraints or foreign keys.

Comment: @Vince You mean there is no way to join tables in a geodatabase file? Then how can the tables be joined in ArcGIS?

Comment: File geodatabase is not a file. It is directory with many files. The "file" in the name is to discriminate it from an RDBMS geodatabase -- same organization, but without the RDBMS overhead (which includes support for JOIN and triggers and constraints, etc.). Joins in ArcGIS Desktop/Server are done the old fashioned way, in the application (which is why I never use them).

Comment: In a file GDB you can create "relationship classes" (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/relationships/benefits-of-relationship-classes.htm) that can be used to help enforce referential integrity between related objects. But I don't know if you can create them using non ESRI software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ogr2ogr` doesn't provide a 'joins' or 'relates' feature for FileGDB. The only tool that I found is `arcpy` (python) which has almost any feature needed to create or modify FileGDB. The method I used to add join (actually 'relates') was `arcpy.CreateRelationshipClass_management`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the name.

File geodatabase is called "file" not because it's formed from one file (which it's not -- that would be *personal* geodatabase, based on the old Microsoft Access format), but to distinguish it from relational database (RDBMS) Enterprise geodatabase (formerly known as ArcSDE).

File geodatabase was created to provide the "table" functionality to drive tables, feature classes, feature datasets, and domains from ArcGIS clients, without the overhead of a full SQL RDBMS. It does not support all the features of a true RDBMS implementation, including triggers, constraints, primary keys, and joins.

Therefore, it is not possible for *any* converter to implement foreign key constraints in file geodatabase (at least, not with a CONSTRAINT keyword in SQL) If you want full RDBMS functionality, you need to use a full RDBMS, or something like SQLite which provides a more SQL-centric experience.